# Angular2 in Google Apps Script Web App

Tags: javascript, angular, google-apps-script, frontend

Is it possible to use Angular2 in Google Apps Script Web App? I searched enough, but there is no documentation/ article on the web which touches this topic.

If it is possible, can anyone give me a sample working Google Apps Script web app using Angular2?

More specifically, I am not sure how to make System.import('app') work in Google Apps script as Google apps does not allow reference to file this way.

Thanks

Comment: Apps Script doesn't have a file system that has folders and sub-folders that can be referenced to load resources.  But you can put client code into an HTML file, and then inject that code into a script tag with templated HTML.  You should probably look at the scriptlets example.  [Apps Script documentation - Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)  You should probably use a printing scriptlet.  There are 3 types of scriptlets.  So, put the code for "app" in an HTML file, and name it "JS_app", and then "include" that "JS_app" file with templated HTML.

Comment: I have been using this template feature for Angular 1.x, however for Angular 2+, the approach of loading/bootstrapping does not seem work with template. System.import refers to the actual file rather than template injection. Do you have any working reference for Angular2 with Google Apps Script?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Angular, so I don't have any info.  Hopefully someone else will be able to help.

Comment: @Jasperin, were you able to use angular in google apps script?

Answer (score 0):

Actually i did integrate Vuejs with Google Apps Script / HtmlService class

U have to use vue as cdn and write all ur page in a single file.

But the HtmlService is not designed for building web pages in production.

It is useful in building sidebars in google sheets.

I recommend to use Google apps script as web application / api it is so powerful and stable

U can check my tutorials [playlist.mashoun.com](https://Playlist.mashoun.com)